# Django Social Auth w/ Twitter: HTTP 401 Error (Unauthorized)

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth

I've followed a couple tutorials for using Django Social Auth Twitter authentication. I'm running Django 1.5 w/ SQLite. I keep getting a HTTP 401 Error (Unauthorized) when trying to log in. I'll paste code below and the error message below that:

## settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/members/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = 'l2Ja2PpNgYYuprGjVXKTA'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = '2W00pBjTp9nIuRSlq3dXQb4atb97z9yFAPZl84H2xI'

SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('twitter',)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends', # Twitter OAuth
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'social_auth',
)
```

## urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', include('companies.urls')),
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')), # Twitter user authentication
   url(r'^', include('companies.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

## Sample template

```
<a href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'twitter' %}">Login with Twitter</a>
```

## Error message

```
HTTPError at /login/twitter/
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/twitter/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: HTTPError
Exception Value:    
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Exception Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in http_error_default, line 521
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/AlexanderPease/git/usv/investor_signal',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PdbSublimeTextSupport-0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 6 Aug 2013 14:28:48 -0400
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/decorators.py in wrapper
            return func(request, request.social_auth_backend, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py in auth
    return auth_process(request, backend) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py in auth_process
        return HttpResponseRedirect(backend.auth_url()) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py in auth_url
        token = self.unauthorized_token() ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py in unauthorized_token
        return Token.from_string(self.fetch_response(request)) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py in fetch_response
        response = dsa_urlopen(request.to_url()) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/utils.py in dsa_urlopen
    return urlopen(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in open
            response = meth(req, response) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in http_response
                'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in error
            return self._call_chain(*args) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in _call_chain
            result = func(*args) ...
▶ Local vars
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) ...
▶ Local vars
Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'EK2I2daqmaKUk4a4GMkQE49mxbmoKYoh'
messages    
'f293b0ecd1cabdde085b9bdd9bcb5d1384cd3668$[["__json_message",0,20,"The us v_ member \\"Nick\\" was added successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The investor \\"O\'Reilly AlphaTech Ventures\\" was added successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The location \\"San Francisco\\" was added successfully. You may add another location below."],["__json_message",0,20,"The location \\"New York\\" was added successfully."]]'
META
Variable    Value
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT  
'no'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
LOGNAME 
'AlexanderPease'
USER    
'AlexanderPease'
PATH    
'/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin'
QUERY_STRING    
''
HOME    
'/Users/AlexanderPease'
DISPLAY 
'/tmp/launch-Mc5F9V/org.macosforge.xquartz:0'
TERM_PROGRAM    
'iTerm.app'
LANG    
'en_US.UTF-8'
TERM    
'xterm'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
TZ  
'America/New_York'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'messages="f293b0ecd1cabdde085b9bdd9bcb5d1384cd3668$[[\\"__json_message\\"\\0540\\05420\\054\\"The us v_ member \\\\\\"Nick\\\\\\" was added successfully.\\"]\\054[\\"__json_message\\"\\0540\\05420\\054\\"The investor \\\\\\"O\'Reilly AlphaTech Ventures\\\\\\" was added successfully.\\"]\\054[\\"__json_message\\"\\0540\\05420\\054\\"The location \\\\\\"San Francisco\\\\\\" was added successfully. You may add another location below.\\"]\\054[\\"__json_message\\"\\0540\\05420\\054\\"The location \\\\\\"New York\\\\\\" was added successfully.\\"]]"; csrftoken=EK2I2daqmaKUk4a4GMkQE49mxbmoKYoh'
SERVER_NAME 
'1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION    
'2.7'
SHLVL   
'1'
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET    
'10.8'
SECURITYSESSIONID   
'186a5'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
ITERM_SESSION_ID    
'w0t0p0'
_   
'/usr/bin/python'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
PATH_INFO   
u'/login/twitter/'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   
'/tmp/launch-nKNyCz/Listeners'
wsgi.input  
<socket._fileobject object at 0x1033000d0>
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render  
'/tmp/launch-cnZeLv/Render'
HTTP_HOST   
'127.0.0.1:8000'
wsgi.multithread    
True
ITERM_PROFILE   
'Zander'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
TMPDIR  
'/var/folders/81/g6ky04gn6pg7mtnfry561l2r0000gn/T/'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once   
False
CSRF_COOKIE 
u'EK2I2daqmaKUk4a4GMkQE49mxbmoKYoh'
OLDPWD  
'/Users/AlexanderPease'
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
wsgi.errors 
<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x1019bb270>
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING 
'0x1F5:0:0'
Apple_Ubiquity_Message  
'/tmp/launch-k9pzeV/Apple_Ubiquity_Message'
PWD 
'/Users/AlexanderPease/git/usv/investor_signal'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'usv_investor_signal.settings'
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
REMOTE_HOST 
''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip,deflate,sdch'
COMMAND_MODE    
'unix2003'
Settings
Using settings module usv_investor_signal.settings
Setting Value
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'usv_investor_signal.urls'
MANAGERS    
()
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
STATIC_ROOT 
''
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS 
False
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
ADMIN_FOR   
()
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M')
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': '/Users/AlexanderPease/git/usv/investor_signal/usv_investor_signal/sqlite3.db',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST_CHARSET': None,
             'TEST_COLLATION': None,
             'TEST_MIRROR': None,
             'TEST_NAME': None,
             'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
             'USER': ''}}
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
APPEND_SLASH    
True
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH   
16
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
USE_I18N    
True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
SECRET_KEY  
u'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
TRANSACTIONS_MANAGED    
False
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'django.utils.log.dictConfig'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS    
('twitter',)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'usv_investor_signal.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
('social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
DEBUG   
True
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS  
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'south',
 'companies',
 'vcdelta',
 'social_auth')
LANGUAGES   
(('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy-nl', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'))
COMMENTS_ALLOW_PROFANITIES  
False
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME    
'new_social_auth_user'
STATICFILES_DIRS    
()
PREPEND_WWW 
False
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
LOGIN_URL   
'/login/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH   
16
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y')
LOGIN_ERROR_URL 
'/login-error/'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
u'********************'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY    
u'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET 
u'********************'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH 
16
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/members/'
PROJECT_ROOT    
'/Users/AlexanderPease/git/usv/investor_signal'
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
()
LOCALE_PATHS    
()
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FIXTURE_DIRS    
()
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
ADMINS  
()
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
MEDIA_URL   
''
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
('/Users/AlexanderPease/git/usv/investor_signal/usv_investor_signal/templates',)
SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH  
16
SITE_ID 
1
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
()
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
()
LOGGING 
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'filters': {'require_debug_false': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'}},
 'handlers': {'mail_admins': {'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                              'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                              'level': 'ERROR'}},
 'loggers': {'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                                'level': 'ERROR',
                                'propagate': True}},
 'version': 1}
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
u'********************'
TIME_ZONE   
'America/New_York'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
('django.core.context_processors.request',
 'django.core.context_processors.static',
 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends')
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'usv_investor_signal.settings'
USE_ETAGS   
False
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
('he', 'ar', 'fa')
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
INTERNAL_IPS    
()
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
EMAIL_PORT  
25
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
USE_TZ  
True
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
u'********************'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y')
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
PROFANITIES_LIST    
u'********************'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 500 page.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, stop what you're doing--you need to go on Twitter and reset your keys for the app because you appear to have placed your TWITTER_APP_KEY and TWITTER_APP_SECRET in your question.  Update your settings.py with your new keys.

Ok?  Done?  Good.  Assuming you've got the proper auth keys in your application:

Problem number 1: As far as I recall off the top of my head, twitter does not allow oauth requests from anything BUT port 80.  Django's dev server 8000 is going to cause you problems (other services work just fine though).

To test locally, we're going to do the following things:

1. Remap your hosts file for local testing:
   If you're running under Windows, update your HOSTS file %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (on linux, it's /etc/hosts/) and map your site's domain name to 127.0.0.1.

   This is helpful when you're testing code locally that relies on external callbacks.  It doesn't always matter (facebook is MORE than happy to callback your app on localhost:8000 .. twitter, as I recall, is not).
2. Start django development server on port 80.

   `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`
3. Open your application settings on twitter's website.  Place your real domain in the website field.
4. In the 'Callback URL' place a DUMMY url on your domain.  This setting does NOT matter as long as a valid url is in this field.  I like to use http://whateveryoururlis.com/dummy-url. This information can be found here: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/twitter.html .. I assume this has to be a url under your domain, I've never tried it with a completely random domain.
5. Check 'Allow this application to be used to sign in with twitter'
6. Open your favorite browser and navigate to your real domain name (which will resolve to django's development server on your local machine since we remapped the host file in step 1).  You should now be able to login with twitter.

As a point of interest, django social auth is depreciated and the author recommends migrating to python-social-auth, which supports django.

Lastly.. I just realized this question was from august.. but someone posted an answer yesterday, which prompted me to write all this before realizing it's such an old question.  Hope it helps someone though!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you set wrong callback URL on your Twitter application settings.
Set `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` as callback URL when you run in local environment.

See this: http://c2journal.com/2013/01/24/social-logins-with-django/

Answer (score -2):

Double check our API keys and the settings for the App you added to your Twitter account. It looks like twitter is denying you access because it cannot validate the details.

Comment: This is not an answer